# How to embed Chromium Embbeded Framework into GLFW

Tags: opengl, glfw, chromium-embedded

I am trying to do as the title implies. I am looking for a tutorial or an existing github project that will show me how to make this possible. As far as what I have or haven't tryed: nothing. I have been at a lose of documentation on CEF and don't know where to begin. I am aware of the alternatives (librocket, awesomium, and berkelium). If any of these have been embbeded in GLFW successfully link appropriately. As far as finding no documentation, I have looked on CEF's website and wiki and found installation instructions and an example that uses `#include <window.h>` instead of opengl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a bit of massaging to get it to work, as the libcef.so file is too big to be stored on github and the cef implementation is a few years old, however, I've posted a few "issues" with fixes and suggestions here to assist you.  The software here is pretty good however it's completely lacking of decent documentation, and it depends greatly upon what directory you launch it from.  Big hint: Launch the software from the base directory of this git.

https://github.com/andmcgregor/cefgui

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit too much for a novice programmer. GLFW is a down-to-the-absolute-minium framework for creating OpenGL applications. CEF on the other hand depends on many utilities provided by the application it's built into. GLFW doesn't offer them, so you have to implement them in a way that CEF can live within GLFW. That's feasible, but requires some expierience. If you look at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage there's one short paragraph "Off-Screen Rendering". This is what you want to integrate it into a OpenGL project. Render off-screen and present the result through a textured quad (either viewport space aligned).

Comment: When I say novice I only mean so in certain fields because I have tons of Java experience and opengl and glfw aren't new to me either. what I am new to however is CEF and how to integrate it so thank you for the link.

Comment: Do you recommend I use a different library?